# get button in movieclip to go to another frame inside the same movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have several website pages set up on different frames inside the content (which is a movieclip) of the home page - which is on frame 1 of the main timeline. The content movieclip name is contentMc.

My About page is at frame 10. There is a button on this page (called btnAbout_contactpg) that I want to make jump to my Contact page (frame 50) - all of which is nested under the main contentMc movieclip.

This is the pathway on my contentMc (where all of my pages are located), just in case that doesn't make sense: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-YHqWuWYUkME/TuuwcRzUkaI/AAAAAAAAAXM/47EwKEr0uTk/s193/pathway.png

I cannot figure out how to do this. I have looked at several different instructions online, but none of them seem to work.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I am also trying to get a button on my gallery page to load an external image, but it is not recognizing where the button is either:

```
btnGallery_1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showPic1);
function showPic1 (e:MouseEvent) {
    var target:Object=e.target;
    var parent=target.parent;
    my_loader.load(new URLRequest("image-0.jpg"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnAbout_contactpg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoContact);
function gotoContact(e:MouseEvent){
    var target:Object=e.target;
    var parent=target.parent;
    // if your "pages" are themselves movieclips, you will probably need to uncomment out the line below
    //parent=parent.parent;
    parent.gotoAndStop(50);
}
```

At first glance, this should work.

UPDATE:
Lemme guess... your button (btnAbout_contactpg) is only on frame 50...

...so the code you have on your main timeline (presumably on frame 1) is trying to add a listener to an object that won't exist for another 49 frames...

Therefore, barring a complete revamp of your movie's structure (to better utilize the Display model - addChild(), removeChild(), addChildAt(), etc.), I'm going to suggest doing something that is considered BAD PRACTICE.  Add the code (to add the listener) to the button to the frame where the button appears.  You may need to alter the path when specifying the callback though.  Something like:

```
btnAbout_contactpg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.parent.gotoContact);
```

Comment: I tried it with and without the parent=parent.parent; line and this is the error I got both times:  1120 Access of undefined property btnAbout_contactpg. The other methods I have tried did the same thing. I'm wondering if the pathway is not connecting to the button name correctly.

Comment: I put the code you suggested on my actions layer on the main timeline - is that the right spot? It's where the rest of my code is.

Comment: You've asked the same question before, slightly different, and got the same answer - perhaps it's time you started looking at some tutorials on how to use the timeline and on basic ActionScript now...

Comment: Check my UPDATE.

Also, you might want to delve into the display tools more.  It makes updating the items on your stage a trivial process.

...of course, you might also want to look into the Cairngorm framework.  With a little fiddling (ok a LOT if you are using Flash rather than Flex) you could set up a "pageManager" that would eliminate the need to actually use the timeline.  Such a class/object is waaaaaay out of scope for this question though.  I offer it as a suggested resource for your future efforts.

Comment: @Prpl_Ppl_Etr My button is actually only on frame 10 (where my About page is). I'm trying to have a link that is something like "Click here to see my Contact Page" (then you click and skip to frame 50).

Comment: @Prpl_Ppl_Etr To clarify: this is the code you suggested? btnAbout_contactpg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.parent.gotoContact);
function gotoContact(e:MouseEvent){
    var target:Object=e.target;
    var parent=target.parent;
    // if your "pages" are themselves movieclips, you will probably need to uncomment out the line below
    parent=parent.parent;
    parent.gotoAndStop(50);
}

Comment: I put that code on the same frame that the button is on. I received this error code: 

Symbol 'contentMc', Layer 'buttons', Frame 10, Line 1 1119: Access of possibly undefined property gotoContact through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: Yes that is the code I suggested, but since I don't know your specific structure, I can't possible provide you with the actual definitive paths.  I figured you'd be able to determine it once I showed you what was required.

...or after @weltraumpirat told you something similar...

If the concept of parent/child relationships between movieclips, and the resulting path requirements is still confusing to you, you REALLLLLLY need to spend the afternoon doing a few tutorials on the subject.  This is about as basic a conecpt as you're going to run into in Flash programming.  

Good Luck!

Comment: @Prpl_Ppl_Etr Hence why I'm glad Flash is pretty much dead. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @user1102296 You will run into similar problems with other languages, unless you start trying to understand the basic concepts of programming. It's easy to bash Flash, but most of the horrific ActionScript-based applications out there are just very badly coded. That's what you get for making people think that moving a few keyframes makes you a web designer.